# How to do QtWidgets.QTableWidget.setHorizontalHeader() to maintain default behavior?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

pyqt5. Regular table:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(3, 3)

table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3'])

table.show()
app.exec_()
```

Here, clicking on column header selects the whole column.

If I try to pass explicitly the QtWidgets.QHeaderView, I lose some of the default behavior, notably clicking on header no longer selects the column:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class CustomTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

table = CustomTableWidget(3, 3)
table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3'])
table.show()

app.exec_()
```

I tried selecting different parent widgets for QHeaderView including the table, subclassing QHeaderView, etc.
Could not achieve default behavior. (I obviously wouldn't want to reimplement explicitly the defaults from scatch)

Answer (score 0):

QTableWidget for some weird reason does additional steps during init (https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/itemviews/qtableview.cpp#n587) instead of subclassing QHeaderView. Therefore to get full default behavior, need to implement those additional steps:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class CustomTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.header = QtWidgets.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.header.setSectionsClickable(True)  # From QTableWidget's init
        self.header.setHighlightSections(True)  # From QTableWidget's init
        self.setHorizontalHeader(self.header)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(self.header)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
table = CustomTableWidget(3, 3)
table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3'])
table.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: While the solution is correct, the explanation is not. QTableWidget does nothing on its own, it just follows the default behavior of QTableView (also explained in [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#visual-appearance)) from which QTableWidget inherits. And it should not subclass QHeaderView, since it would be pointless.

Answer (score -1):

You have a normal table, and when trying to subclass it you lose the default behavior of being able to select columns ?

That will be since you added the line `self.setHorizontalHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal))` .
When you make a declaration like this its going to override any default behavior inbuilt.
Removing it will give your expected result.

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class CustomTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # @SomebodyYoung Do not set a new horizontal header explicitly as it will just override the normal set behaviour

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
table = CustomTableWidget(3, 3)
table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3'])
table.show()
app.exec()
```

I made thin as a PyQT6 version as its most recent, but do change anyway you want.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Also See [Links on Subclassing](https://www.codesdope.com/course/python-subclass-of-a-class/) here. They will help you understand better.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, since the OP is clearly asking how to set another header while *also* keeping the default behavior, which is a perfectly valid question since the alternate header may be a subclass that implements other aspects.